# General way for managing duplicate entities in different parent entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have such models:

```
public class EntityFirst
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EntityThirdId { get; set; }

    public virtual EntityThird { get; set; }
}

public class EntitySecond
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EntityThirdId { get; set; }

    public virtual EntityThird { get; set; }
}

public class EntityThird 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // These columns are unique together
    public int DocumentType { get; set; }
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I must insert `EntityFirst` and `EntitySecond` objects to database. But `EntityThird` has some uniqueness, `DocumentType` and `DocumentNumber` are unique together. So, before calling `SaveChanges` I am checking if such `EntityThird` exists in the database or not. If it exists, then I am taking it's `Id` and setting to parent's `EntityThirdId` and of course changing state of this entity to `Detached`.

So far, so good.

**The problem is:**

What if, `EntityFirst` and `EntitySecond` has `EntityThird` objects, which both have same `DocumentType` and `DocumentNumber`. In such sutuation, I must insert only one of them to the database and get newly inserted object `Id`. And then set `EntityThirdId` value in both entities to this `Id`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

Currently, I have let's say two entities and of course two objects in the heap. So, EF were trying to insert both entities to the database. I have thought that, if both these entities will reference to the same address, then EF will insert only one of these. Of course also I need to make another entity or entities *(in case of more than 2 same entities)* `Detached`.

And, that solve my problem.

As an additional note, I am sharing some parts of the code so others can use it:

```
// Here I find all this type of entities which has Added state
var addedEntities = context.Set<TEntity>()
              .Local
              .AsEnumerable();
```

Then, I am checking for all entities if there is any other same entity or you can use `GroupBy` here and so on based on your requirements

```
// parent - This is an owner entity
if (addedEntities.Count(x => ...) > 1)
{
    parent.GetType()
          .GetProperty("MyTypeName")
          .SetValue(parent, addedEntities.LastOrDefault(...));

    // Detach your object here...
}
```